# Trouble with LINQ Returning Results Set from Object[] Array Within Object

Tags: asp.net, linq, ienumerable, paging, iqueryable

Consider the following code:

```
var articlesDisplay = from product in db.ProductSearchData
                      select product.articles;

articlesDisplay = articlesDisplay.Where(a => a[].body.Contains(searchString));
```

I'm trying to load a results set, but get a compiler error using the array notation in the Where clause.  How should I be going about this?

The desired end result is a var articlesDisplay object that can be used in ASP.NET MVC pagination.

Thanks to any/all for your assistance!

Comment: What is `a[].body` supposed to mean?  Are you new to lambda expressions?

Comment: Well somewhat, but not THAT new.  I realize a[].body isn't the right notation - I am wondering what is....

Comment: Right. So what is it *supposed to* mean? What is the requirement?  I can’t tell what the right answer is from looking at the wrong answer.

Comment: So let me do an article with the JSON source in question....see another post further to this very soon.

Comment: <!-- language-all: lang.js -->

{
  "totalCount": 59,
  "pageIndex": 1,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "count": 20,
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": "215098235",
      "title": "LES JEUNES QUI S'ENROLENT DANS L'ARMÉE",
      "subtitle": null,
      "byline": "Radio-canada Première - Faites Du Bruit",
      "body": "NICOLAS OUELLET...enfant dans une tente, puis une autre qui fait des push-up au-dessus de...
            }
          ]
        },
      ...
      },
     ...
    }

Comment: Sorry about above - was the best I could do posting JSON here....

Comment: Additional JSON excerpt included as "answer" below....

Answer (score 2):

remove the array notation

```
var articlesDisplay = from product in db.ProductSearchData
                      select product.articles;

articlesDisplay = articlesDisplay.Where(a => a.body.Contains(searchString));
```

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is just like a function declaration, but instead of `method name(paramters){body }` it takes the form of `parameters => body`. So this:

```
a => a[].body.Contains(searchString)
```

Is the same as this:

```
bool Method(Article article)
{
    return article[].body.Contains(searchString);
}
```

That is obviously not valid, since it won't compile. You need a `Func<T,bool>`, or a function that accepts a single element and returns true or false depending on whether it is to be included. So you probably want this:

```
bool Method(Article article)
{
    return article.body.Contains(searchString);
}
```

Which translates to this:

```
a => a.body.Contains(searchString).
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this for me, please?  In my attempt what I got from the above was:

 articlesDisplay = articlesDisplay.Where(a => GetArticle(a, searchString)>;

And I'm still getting a compiler error on the a object above in GetArticle().....there's a type difference between the first a and the second, the first is ProductsData.Article[] type and the second is a ProductsData.Article type.  They don't cast.

Tnx for your continued assistance!